# How do I override web.xml context-param values at runtime in JBoss 5

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss5.x

Tomcat has support for deploying a WebApp using just a context descriptor that, when dropped into the correct directory, can override context-params and point to the actual WAR file to run.  These context descripts look like...

```
<Context
  reloadable="true"
  docBase="/Users/bobk/work/workspace/xproject/dist/xproject.war">
    <Parameter
      name="ATGRestURLPrefix"
      value="http://bobk-mbp.local:8180/rest/bean/"
      type="java.lang.String"
      override="false" />
</Context>
```

We are running with JBoss 5 here and I've been over the documentation and cannot find a way to do this in a JBoss environment.  In JBoss 5, my only choices appear to be straight WAR deployment into a server/blahBlahBlah/deploy directory OR exploded WAR deployment into the same server/blahBlahBlah/deploy directory.  With the exploded WAR it is possible that the web.xml could be edited, but I am trying to avoid this.  I would much rather give our Ops folks a single file to edit to override some context-param values I initialize in the WebApp's web.xml file.

How is context-param override achieved in a JBoss 5 environment?

Comment: Make bob sad.  24 hours and no answer.  My research has come up blank as well.  My immediate problem, how to get a property value overridden at runtime, is solvable in JBoss 5 using something called the properties-service.xml file which is located in the deploy folder.  This makes these dynamically configurable values available to my java code via plain-jane System.getProperty().  It is rather disappointing, however, that JBoss 5 has no solution for this seemingly simple java-ee Webapp challenge.